# sed is replacing whole line instead of just the string

Tags: sed

I want to just replace few strings in file with nothing, but sed replaces the whole line. Can someone help me with this?

line in file.xml:

```
<tag>sample text1 text2</tag>
```

My code:

```
 sed "s/'text1 text2'//" file.xml 2>/dev/null || :
```

I also tried

```
 sed -i -e "s/'text1 text2'//" file.xml 2>/dev/null || :
```

expected result:

```
<tag>sample</tag>
```

Actual result:

```
The whole line is removed from file.
```

Others:

```
text1 and text 2 are complex text with .=- characters in it
```

What can I do to fix this?

TIA

Comment: That regex doesn't match the line you've shown us, so there must be something else going on. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes:

```
sed "s/text1 text2//" file.xml
```

Comment: It still removes the line

Comment: Well that's puzzling.  It works for me.    $ sed "s/text1 text2//" txt.xml
---->    <tag>sample </tag>

Comment: Maybe cos I have an example which does not match reality! what if text1 and text 2 have characters - & = in them? e.g text1 is actually -text=1 and text2 is actually -text=2? So I need to replace -text=1 -text=2 with nothing

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\)[^<]*\(.*\)/\1\2/' filename
```

Output:

```
<tag>sample</tag>
```

Grouping is used. First all characters till a space are grouped together, then all characters till a `<` are matched and all following characters are grouped into another group.